# System.Net.WebException: Невозможно разрешить удаленное имя: 'soap.search.msn.com'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Пытаюсь запустить пример, описанный [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc163355.aspx), компиляция проходит успешно. Но после того, как нажимаю на кнопку search выходит ошибка: System.Net.WebException: Невозможно разрешить удаленное имя: 'soap.search.msn.com'. Собственно [исходник](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/Search2007_09.exe). Использую .NET 4.0.

Трассировка стека:

```
[WebException: Невозможно разрешить удаленное имя: 'soap.search.msn.com']
   LiveSearchProvider.ExecuteQuery(String queryText, String culture, Int32 resultsPerPage, Int32 resultsPageIndex, Boolean highlight) in e:\helio\practice\c#\Search\App_Code\LiveSearchProvider.cs:79
   SearchEngine.ExecuteQuery() in e:\helio\practice\c#\Search\App_Code\SearchEngine.cs:84
   Search.RunSearch() in e:\helio\practice\c#\Search\Search.aspx.cs:40
   Search.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\helio\practice\c#\Search\Search.aspx.cs:29
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +37
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +134
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3413
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто данный сервис

> http://soap.search.msn.com/webservices.asmx

, который используется в примере для поиска, сдох.

Comment: А есть ли какая-то альтернатива?

Comment: Например гугл: https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/?hl=ru - 100 бесплатных запросов в день.

Comment: Естественно ваш пример 2007 года приидется переделать.