# Невозможно разрешить удалённое имя

Tags: c#, вконтакте, vknet

Запускаю у себя - всё нормально.
Запускает друг - ошибка. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
VkApi vk = new VkApi();
vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
{
     AccessToken = token
});
var users = vk.Messages.GetChatUsers(new long[] { 1205 }, VkNet.Enums.Filters.UsersFields.City, VkNet.Enums.SafetyEnums.NameCase.Nom);
```

Comment: В локации твоего друга запрещён DNS VK, вот ещё https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/218750/system-net-webexception-Невозможно-разрешить-удаленное-имя-soap-search-msn-co

Comment: @DigitalCore спасибо, помог!